# Having multiple breakpoints for nav links in Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm implementing Foundation 5 on one of my sites.  I have the top bar mostly working.  However, I want to be able to collapse a set of nav links into a dropdown menu at a certain breakpoint.

Basically, instead of just collapsing from the full nav to the one mobile nav dropdown, I want an intermediate step that first collapses to 2-3 links, and then only on very small screens collapses the rest of the way.

I've been looking around for how to do this and am not finding it in the documentation.  Any ideas?

Comment: please code (jquery, javascript)

Comment: For anyone that sees this questioon in the future I wanted to let you know that I figured it out.  What you want to look up is Foundation's visibility classes.  That allows you to only show content at certain screen sizes.